# Is there alternate versions of What's Your Raashee?

Tags: alternate-version, whats-your-raashee

I have seen [What's Your Raashee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What%27s_Your_Raashee%3F) in theater and forceful cuts of the film were easily noticeable. But few years ago, I have seen it in Indian broadcast channel and this version of film had two extra songs , which were equally essential to understand two of the twelve girls.  I did googled a lot about it but can't find anything about additional versions.

So my question is what are all the versions of What's Your Raashee and what are the difference in them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's more of mid-week edit to reduce the length of the film by removing three songs, from [Hindustan Times](https://www.hindustantimes.com/india/three-songs-cut-from-what-s-your-raashee/story-QBwzxqzaLa4Lu7Gzgy899I.html):

> The original print of the movie featured 13 songs in all — one song
>   representing each zodiac sign, and a title track. But since mid-week,
>   three songs have been removed from the new version of the film.
>
> Director Gowariker confirmed the same, “The audiences were feeling
>   that the film could have lesser songs, so now the film is running with
>   three songs less.”
>
> Gowariker also admitted that the songs could have been a reason that
>   the film seemed daunting to some section of the audiences.
>
> He says, “Because there are 12 ‘raashees’ and I wanted to have one
>   song represent each ‘raashee’, the 12 songs piled up, and that’s why
>   people probably felt the burden of it.”
>
> Though Gowariker didn’t reveal the songs that he has cut and declined
>   to comment on why the particular songs were chosen, it is learnt that
>   two of the songs are ‘Maanunga maanunga’, which was incidentally sung
>   by Gowariker himself, and ‘Salone kya’.

Also, I watched the TV broadcast version again some time back and yes there were those three songs present there which were missing in the theater version. Also [DVD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0030EW75O)
movie length also seems to be with those three songs.

I also got to know all three songs which were missing in theater version which are  ‘Maanunga maanunga’ used for Rajni Parmar (Tula aka Libra sunshine), "Salone Kya" for Bhavna Shukla (Dhanu aka Sagittarius sunshine) and "Dhadkan Dhadkan" used for Mallika Desai (Simha aka Leo sunshine).

I do feel these songs were not that necessary but Mallika's song cut was very abrupt and seems off and Bhavna's song was fun.

There was no other change in the film I can spot.

Comment: Congratulations, this is the winner of the [monthly answer challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4417/49).